# Custom Error message using passport Bearer

Tags: node.js, rest, passport.js, bearer-token

I'm using passport to secure my API.
I kind of struggle to understand how i'm supposed to send back custom message in case of error and i'm hoping to find an answer here.

Here is what i did:

A route (server.js):

```
router.route('/Applications').get(authController.BearerAuthenticated, applicationController.getApplications);
```

My Passport Stuff (authController.js):

```
Passport.use(new BearerStrategy(function(token, cb) {
Token.findOne({token: token}, function(err, token){ 
    if (err){return cb(null, false);}
    if (!token) { return cb(null, false); }
    return cb(null, token);
});
}));

exports.BearerAuthenticated = Passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false});
```

My Application method (Application.js)

```
exports.getApplications = function(req, res) {
Application.find({userId:req.user._id}, function(err, apps) {
if (err)
  res.send(err);
res.json(apps);
});
};
```

If my token is valid and the Bearer method return

```
return cb(null, token);
```

Then i can enter my getApplications method. It makes sense.

The thing is when the token is not valid, i don't enter the method (makes sense too) but i can't figure out a way to return a custom message to the client instead of the following message i get by default.

```
Unauthorized
```

What would be a way to return a Json with an error code to properly let the user know that his token is dead or simply does not exist ?

Thanks for you time. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a callback in `authenticate` and handle errors from there. Note that in this case you have to manually perform the default operations like user login etc. More on it in [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/935fbdbc2f63eb0a746a3e1373fb112c5efee6b6/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L23-L40).

```
exports.BearerAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        //authentication error
        if (!user) { return res.json({error: info.message || 'Invalid Token'}) }

        //success 
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          return next();
        });

    })(req, res, next)
}
```