# Passport.js change default error message

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Passport.js for authentication in my node/express app, when input fields are empty passport displays default message "Missing credentials", how can i change that? to say something like please fill the form or something

here my local strategy for login:

```
  passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
      models.User.findOne({where: {email}}).then(user => {
        if (!user)
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Email not registered'});
        user.checkPassword(password).then(res => {
          if (!res)
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username or password'});
          return done(null, user);
        });
      });
    }));
```

login route:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

Comment: You can try `if (!email && !password) return done(null, false, { message: "Missing credentials" })`

Comment: Try it before the `models.User.findOne...` line

Comment: i already tried that does not work

Comment: What does it say? Does it output anything?

Comment: yeah same does not change anything

Comment: But what does it display? I.e. now

Comment: same "Missing credentials"

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32520810/5423850)?

Comment: um my route is different i don't have access to request and response objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, looks like i can pass optional callback to authenticate function to override default functionality, thanks oneturkmen for reference.

here's modified route:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('signup', (err, user, info) => {
    const body = req.body;
    if (req.body.username === '' || req.body.email === '' || req.body.password === '')
      info.message = 'Please fill the form';
    req.logIn(user, err => {
      if (err) res.render('users/signup', info);
      else res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to add "**badRequestMessage**" to your code

Your code will look like this

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  badRequestMessage : 'Please fill the form',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```